# In what situations will you lose the low-pot in Omaha Hi/Lo while holding Ace-Deuce?

Tags: poker-theory, reading-hands, omaha-hi-lo, nuts

In Omaha hi low, will holding an Ace and a Deuce card automatically give you the "nut low" hand in the event of a qualifying low hand?

Comment: Perhaps an Ace or 2 is on the board.  Then the opponents won't need to hold that card to beat you.  E.g. if board is A 4 6 7 8, and your opponent holds 23, then they will beat you.

Comment: @Mew You have the start of a good answer there. Would you mind turning it into one ?

Answer (score 5):

You can only **lose** the low hand if you get counterfeit (when a low card hits the board that also pairs one of your low cards), so that you don't hold the nut low on the river anymore.

If there is a low hand possible, and no A or 2 on the board, you always have the nut low. At worst, you will split the low pot if someone else also has a A2XX hand. With that said, it is possible to win a quarter of the whole pot (50% of low pot and 0% of high pot).

Comment: I "won" a tenth of a pot once with A2. Lost about $20.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

You have A2, villain has A3.

Board is: 24567.

That gives you a low: A2456

Gives villain low: A2345

Basically, whenever one of your cards pairs, you **might** be in danger.

Comment: What if there is a pair on the board that duplicates a card in your hand. For example, two threes on the board and a three in your hand. Can you use on of the threes on the board to make a low hand?

Comment: I would change that "might" to "probably are".

Answer (score 1):

A2 will be nut low when:

1. There are 3 or more different cards 8 of below on the board.
2. None of those three board cards is an A or 2.

It might still be nut low in other cases, for example where either
the A or the 2 completes a wheel with 4 board cards.

But in most--not all--cases, nut low is the having in your hand the
two lowest cards *not on the board*. Pairing your low cards is a bad
thing in Omaha. That's why hands like A23, A24 are much better than
those with "naked" A2--the extra low card is "counterfeit protection",